# Has the modern logic negation $\lnot$ been adapted from Frege's Begriffsschrift?

Tags: notation, mathematical-logic

Has the modern logic negation $\lnot$ been adapted from [Frege's Begriffsschrift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begriffsschrift)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. See [Earliest Uses of Symbols of Set Theory and Logic](http://jeff560.tripod.com/set.html):

> The main symbol for negation wich is used today is $¬$. It was first used in 1930 by [Arend Heyting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arend_Heyting) in “Die formalen Regeln der intuitionistischen Logik,” *Sitzungsberichte der preußischen Akademie der Wissenschaften, phys.-math.Klasse*, 1930, p. 42-65 [see page 43].